# Burn bootloader finishes with "avrdude done. Thank you." but bootloader didn't actually get flashed

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, bootloader, avrdude

I've built a a stripped down version of the Arduino Nano that has some peripherals removed and three connectors for analog sensors I want to use. I'm trying to burn the Arduino Nano bootloader onto this custom board using the sparkFun AVR Pocket Programmer and from the Arduino IDE console it seems to say that it was burned successfully. But when I plug the board back into the computer it still shows up as a COM port instead of an Arduino device. This is the output I get in the console after I press burn bootloader with "USBtinyISP" selected as programmer and Arduino Nano as the board.

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : usbtiny
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found USBtinyISP, bus:device: bus-0:\\.\libusb0-0001--0x1781-0x0c9f
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : USBtiny
         Description     : USBtiny simple USB programmer, https://learn.adafruit.com/usbtinyisp
avrdude: programmer operation not supported

avrdude: Using SCK period of 10 usec
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f (probably m328p)
avrdude: NOTE: "flash" memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: Using SCK period of 10 usec
avrdude: reading input file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex"
avrdude: writing flash (32768 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% -0.00s

avrdude: 32768 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex:
avrdude: input file C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex contains 32768 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 32768 bytes of flash verified
avrdude: reading input file "0x0F"
avrdude: writing lock (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: 1 bytes of lock written
avrdude: verifying lock memory against 0x0F:
avrdude: load data lock data from input file 0x0F:
avrdude: input file 0x0F contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip lock data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of lock verified
```

The burning is pretty much over instantly and you can see the reading and writing take 0.00s, it should be closer to a minute rather than an instantly. It's faster than uploading a simple sketch to the Arduino. When I unplug the programmer and plug the device back via USB, it just shows up as a COM port instead of "Arduino Nano" - which doesn't allow me to program it via the Arduino IDE.

What is very strange to me is that I can program the device over the command line. If I follow the AVR Pock Programmer instructions ["Using AVRDUDE via Command Line"](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pocket-avr-programmer-hookup-guide/all) and use a hex file generated from the Arduino IDE, the code uploads fine and runs fine. I wrote a sketch that prints the ADC values over the command line and after flashing via command line it's running as expected.

I've tried to upload the Arduino booatloader via command line as shown in [this tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/installing-an-arduino-bootloader#uploading-code---hard-way) under "Uploading Code - Hard Way" and this time it takes over 43 seconds to write to flash and 30 seconds to read from flash so I thought it worked. However when I plug it back in, it STILL just comes up on my computer and the Arduino IDE as COM9.

This is the output I get when trying to flash the bootloader via command line:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\bootloaders\optiboot
λ avrdude -b 19200 -c usbtiny -p m328p -v -e -U efuse:w:0x05:m -U hfuse:w:0xD6:m -U lfuse:w:0xFF:m

avrdude: Version 5.10, compiled on Jan 19 2010 at 10:45:23
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\WinAVR-20100110\bin\avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : lpt1
         Using Programmer              : usbtiny
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
         AVR Part                      : ATMEGA328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65     5     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : USBtiny
         Description     : USBtiny simple USB programmer, http://www.ladyada.net/make/usbtinyisp/
avrdude: programmer operation not supported

avrdude: Using SCK period of 10 usec
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.06s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f
avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as DE
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as 5
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: Using SCK period of 10 usec
avrdude: reading input file "0x05"
avrdude: writing efuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: 1 bytes of efuse written
avrdude: verifying efuse memory against 0x05:
avrdude: load data efuse data from input file 0x05:
avrdude: input file 0x05 contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip efuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of efuse verified
avrdude: reading input file "0xD6"
avrdude: writing hfuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: 1 bytes of hfuse written
avrdude: verifying hfuse memory against 0xD6:
avrdude: load data hfuse data from input file 0xD6:
avrdude: input file 0xD6 contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip hfuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of hfuse verified
avrdude: reading input file "0xFF"
avrdude: writing lfuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse written
avrdude: verifying lfuse memory against 0xFF:
avrdude: load data lfuse data from input file 0xFF:
avrdude: input file 0xFF contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip lfuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse verified

avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as D6
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as 5
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK

avrdude done.  Thank you.


C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\bootloaders\optiboot
λ avrdude -b 19200 -c usbtiny -p m328p -v -e -U flash:w:optiboot_atmega328.hex -U lock:w:0x0F:m

avrdude: Version 5.10, compiled on Jan 19 2010 at 10:45:23
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\WinAVR-20100110\bin\avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : lpt1
         Using Programmer              : usbtiny
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
         AVR Part                      : ATMEGA328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65     5     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : USBtiny
         Description     : USBtiny simple USB programmer, http://www.ladyada.net/make/usbtinyisp/
avrdude: programmer operation not supported

avrdude: Using SCK period of 10 usec
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.05s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f
avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as D6
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as 5
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: Using SCK period of 10 usec
avrdude: reading input file "optiboot_atmega328.hex"
avrdude: input file optiboot_atmega328.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: writing flash (32768 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 43.63s



avrdude: 32768 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against optiboot_atmega328.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file optiboot_atmega328.hex:
avrdude: input file optiboot_atmega328.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: input file optiboot_atmega328.hex contains 32768 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 30.69s



avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 32768 bytes of flash verified
avrdude: reading input file "0x0F"
avrdude: writing lock (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: 1 bytes of lock written
avrdude: verifying lock memory against 0x0F:
avrdude: load data lock data from input file 0x0F:
avrdude: input file 0x0F contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip lock data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of lock verified

avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as D6
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as 5
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I've reviewed my schematic multiple times, comparing it to the [actual Nano schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Nano-Rev3.2-SCH.pdf) but I can't see anything that would cause it to fail - it's almost identical ! I've built two of these boards and they behave the same exact same way. Schematic shown below.

[image]

Comment: your post does not make sense ... you are using an FTDI chip, which presents itself as a serial port

Comment: But the FR32RL is the same chip that the Arduino Nano uses - and the Nano shows up as an Arduino Device when it is plugged in. You can program it directly using the Arduino IDE.

Comment: Would I need to do that to use the Arduino IDE for flashing ?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what that means - could you explain a little more?

Comment: old PCs had a DB25 parallel port used for printers ... also called Centronics port ... it had 8 bi-directional data pins and some handshaking pins ... `LPT1` is usually the name for the parallel port as opposed to serial port `COM1`

Comment: Why does it find the device and read/write to flash if the port is wrong ?

Comment: I do not know ... it is just that `lpt1` leaped out when i looked at the printout

Comment: The short flash time makes sense if you think about the size of the bootloader. It should not occupy all of the 32KB! Commonly it is much smaller than the typical sketch. If avrdude tells you that 32KB are flashed, then most of the contents should be 0xFF - please check this. Since 0xFF is the erased byte value of a flash memory, there is nothing to do for these bytes, resulting in very short flash times.

Comment: try a manual reset while avrdude attempts to upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino 'device' is identified by the USB device code of the USB to TTL Serial on Arduino or by core code in case of MCU with native USB. The USB ids are written to the USB chip in factory or are part of the firmware/core and they are listed in boards.txt file so that the IDE then knows what Arduino is attached. If you use a common FTDI it doesn't have this Arduino vid and pid codes, which identifies the device as Arduino.

Note: I think you asked a different question then your real problem is, because you assumed that the name of the port not showing Arduino is the reason why the upload doesn't work. It is so called X->Y problem. You have a problem X but asked about problem Y. I answered the question asked.

Comment: I see. Does that mean it won't be possible to flash this board via the Arduino IDE ? I'll just need to keep flashing through the command line ?

Comment: @VanGo, if you have the right COM port in Tools menu, you can upload. it doesn't have to say 'Arduino'

Comment: I've tried this, but I end up with a bunch of these messages "avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00" and then it fails. I've tried pressing the reset while it's uploading but no difference...

Comment: There are different bootloaders implementing different protocols. You might need to select another protocol/bootloader.

Comment: @VanGo, that is a different question

Comment: @Juraj thanks for the pointers. It was indeed another issue - I had the Arduino Tx/Rx plugged into another device. When I tried uploading code via the Arduino IDE with the Rx/Tx pins unplugged from the other device - it let me upload successfully even though the device still just shows up as a COM port. Thanks !